# code not saving the data into another sheet

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have below code which has to cut the data and copy into another sheet called data_base but its not happening its copying the data in username-password.xlsx and i am facing one more problem is once i try to close the userform Logout button should appear when i click on logout button its giving error at line "Worksheets("data1").Range("B1").Value = Date & " " & Time ' as subscript out of range.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim username As String
Dim password As String

username = TextBox1.Text
password = TextBox2.Text



Dim info
info = IsWorkBookOpen("D:\TMS_Project\username-password.xlsx")

If info = False Then
Workbooks.Open ("D:\TMS_Project\username-password.xlsx")
End If

Dim x As Integer
x = 2
Do While Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
If Cells(x, 1).Value = username And Cells(x, 2).Value = password Then
MsgBox "Welcome!"
Worksheets("data1").Range("A1").Value = Date & " " & Time
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"

UserForm1.Hide
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
End
Else
x = x + 1
End If

Loop
MsgBox "Please check your username or password!"
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox2.Text = ""
TextBox1.SetFocus


End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

Worksheets("data1").Range("B1").Value = Date & " " & Time
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"

ThisWorkbook.Save

Worksheets("data1").Range("A1:B1").Select

Selection.Cut

Unload Me

getlogindata

ActiveWorkbook.Close True

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
Cancel = True
End If

End Sub


Sub getlogindata()

Dim info
info = IsWorkBookOpen("D:\TMS_Project\Log_Details..xlsx")
' we open the workbook if it is closed
If info = False Then
Workbooks.Open ("D:\TMS_Project\Log_Details..xlsx")
End If
Worksheets("data_base").Activate
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("data_base").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 2))

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.Quit

End Sub
```

any help is appreciated as i got stuck at this and could not able to progress with my login and logout system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a sheet called "data1" in the **currently active** workbook. Try fully qualifying the reference as

Workbooks("Log_Details..xlsx").worksheets("data1").range("B1")= Date & " " & Time

or Activate the desired workbook first